# Activity not found exception While launching Internet application from fragmentActivity

Tags: android

```
public void callWebView(String aUrl) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

    intent.setData(Uri.parse(aUrl));
    try {


        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        myContext.startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Log cat :

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=www.twitter.com typ=url flg=0x10000000 }
```

Comment: can you post that url?

Comment: I have found the solution sorry its my mistake I have not added http:// before my url link.

Comment: yep you have to add http:// or https://

Comment: Thanks Mr. Hariharan for your quick response..